# AG Grid Export to Excel: How to Alter the Value of a Cell on Export

Tags: javascript, datagrid, ag-grid, export-to-excel, ag-grid-angular

A heads up that I am mostly new to AG Grid Excel Export and I am having trouble finding an answer to my question. I want to be able to alter the value of a specific cell upon export for example if I have a cell that contains a date of the following format d/m/9999 it should be shown as TBD within the export. I would want to do this purely as part of the export and not as part of the web display. Is this possible? Or is this a change that would need to be implemented prior to the export? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several callbacks provided for such cases, in your case you should use [processCellCallback](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/excel-export-api/#reference-excelExportParams-processCellCallback)

To use this processing only for the export but NOT for the web display, you should do this:

```
function dateCellCallBack(params) {
  // if year===9999, return 'TBD'
}

function onBtExport() {
    var params = {
        processCellCallback: dateCellCallBack,
    };
    gridOptions.api.exportDataAsExcel(params);
}
```